# dispatchKeyEvent() invoking twice

Tags: java, android

I debugged the following snippet and come to know the method `dispatchKeyEvent()` is invoked twice. please suggest the solution

```
    @Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
if(event.getKeyCode()== KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)
    {
        if(cDetail.getVisibility()==View.VISIBLE  )
        {

            cDetail.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            cList.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        else
        {

            cDetail.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            cList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

        }   


    }

    return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: @sakir the answer says to filter event, I am not sure, is it true that KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN & KeyEvent.ACTION_UP are called when you press any key?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

dispatchKeyEvent fire twice: the first time for key down, and the second time for key up, so you have to filter:

```
 if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
                return true;

            switch (keyCode) {
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_1 : 
                MakeToast(1);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_2 : 
                MakeToast(2);
                break;
            case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_3 : 
                MakeToast(3);
                break;

            }
```

Comment: ok...you filtered for KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, what about the KeyEvent.ACTION_UP

Comment: Most keys event on Android invoke on ACTION_UP, so the above code run once on ACTION_UP, just put your code on if statment

Comment: This is a more detailed explanation. Thanks