# KeyEventDispatcher invoked twice in Java

Tags: java, swing, keyevent

In my Swing application, I need to set some global key bindings. I use a KeyEvent Dispatcher for this, like this:

```
public class MyKeyEventDispatcher implements KeyEventDispatcher
{

    @Override
    public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent e)
    {
        if (!e.isConsumed())
        {
            if (e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F8)
            {
                System.out.println("F8");
                e.consume();
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

My problem is that this is invoked twice when I hit the F8, once for keyup and once for keydown. How can I detect if it is the keyup or keydown event?

I thought I found the answer here: [dispatchKeyEvent() invoking twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24121644/dispatchkeyevent-invoking-twice), but unfortunately, that only works in Android.

Comment: Maybe use a `KeyListener`/`KeyAdapter` for this instead? This interface defines one method for key-down and one for key-up (and aditionaly for all displayable chars a key-pressed)

Comment: You should actually get three: KEY_PRESSED, KEY_TYPED and KEY_RELEASED. You can do `e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED` to check the event type. (Though come to think about it, you won't get a KEY_TYPED for F8, as it's a special key.)

Comment: Another thing worth checking is the `getModifiers()` method, unless you want your code to be triggered for Alt+F8, Ctrl+Shift+F8 and so on.

Comment: Ah thx, it's getID()... I just kept overlooking that one

Answer (score 4):

The answer was in the comments from @biziclop: use e.getID() to detect the key event. It was also noted that I should check the modifiers to avoid triggering on Shift+F8, Ctrl+F8 etc.

```
(e.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_F8 && e.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED && e.getModifiers() == 0)
```